# Accessories disappear when scrolling tableview | Swift 5

Tags: swift, uitableview

**What I would like to accomplish:**

I have tableview that is being populated using JSON that is gettings its data from a mySQL database. To decode this JSON I use the following structure:

```
import UIKit

struct Section {
    let name : String
    var items : [Portfolios]
}

struct Portfolios: Decodable {

    let person: String
    let code: String
    let tick: Int
    var isSelected = false

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case person, code, tick
    }

}
```

Two things must happen every time a row is selected and deselected:

**Selected**

**1.)** Checkmark accessory added to row selected.

**2.)** Select() function is executed.

**Deselected**

**1.)** Checkmark accessory removed to row selected.

**2.)** Unselect() function is executed.

ex: Of what a selectRow() and unselectRow() function looks like:

```
func selectRow() {
    let url = "https://example.com/example/"
    let parameters: Parameters = ["code": codeSelected]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString { response in
        print(response)
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** *This function sends the parameter to backend script and changes the "tick" column value for that code from a 1 to a 2.*

When a row is unselected the Unselect() function looks the same but serves to update the record by changing tick from a 2 to 1.

The unselectRow() looks like the following:

```
func unselectRow() {
    let url = "https://example.com/example/"
    let parameters: Parameters = ["code": codeUnselected]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString { response in
        print(response)
    }
}
```

To provide the value of codeSelected I was initially using the `didDeselectRowAt` and `didSelectRowAt`

**ex:**

```
    structure = sections[indexPath.section].code
    let theStructure = structure[indexPath.row]
    rmaUnselected = theStructure.code
```

Using `didDeselectRowAt` and `didSelectRowAt` was causing no issue until I realized the checkmark accessories were disappearing when scrolling far enough.

The one other caveat is if a row is selected the code value is changed for that record the checkmark accessory needs to show up for that row in the tableview as soon as the tableview loads and the row needs to be already selected.

**I have using the following in willDisplay cell**

```
if (theStructure.tick == 2) {
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
} else {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to change what happens when cells are selected and deselected but I still need the code in the select() and unselect() functions to work as well.

**In cellForRowAt I set the checkmark according to isSelected**

```
let item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
```

**And I the following in didSelectRowAt:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last attempt:

As the selection is indicated by `tick` the `isSelected` property is actually redundant but you can use it to convert the `Int` value to a more suitable `Bool`. To be able to modify `tick` make it mutable.

And please name `Portfolio` in singular form

```
struct Portfolio: Decodable {

    let person: String
    let code: String
    var tick: Int

    var isSelected : Bool {
        get { return tick == 2 }
        set { tick = newValue ? 2 : 1 }
    }

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case person, code, tick
    }
}
```

Replace `selectRow` with `updateSelection(of:at:)` which takes a `Portfolio` parameter and an `indexPath`. The table view is reloaded only if the network request was successful. I don't know what string the Alamofire request returns. It would be still more secure to first update the database and then update `Portfolio`.

```
func updateSelection(of portfolio: Portfolio, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let url = portfolio.isSelected ? "https://example.com/example/selected" : "https://example.com/example/unselected"
    let parameters: Parameters = [portfolio.code: portfolio.tick]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let string): self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }        

    }
}
```

In `didSelectRowAt` toggle `isSelected` (which updates `tick` implicitly) and update the database.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    let portfolio = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    updateSelection(of: portfolio, at: indexPath)
}
```

You can leave the code in `cellForRow`

```
let item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
```

but delete the method `willDisplayCell`

Comment: Thank you for your help, just a quick note, when unselecting a selected row the opposite function must execute, I updated the post to clarify

Comment: If `codeSelected` is represented by `2` and `codeUnselected` is represented by `1` the method `updateSelection` does both.

Comment: The url for both select and unselect is different in the two functions

Comment: Again I really appreciate your help, just a really quick question, when deselecting a row it takes two taps. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: I suspect there is still other logic in your code which manipulates selection. Remove it.

Comment: You are correct, I had something else leftover from an earlier attempt. Thanks again @Vadian